# How to show a different quick launch menu for each page

Tags: quick-launch

I am new to SharePoint so this may be a silly question but I haven't found anything online prior to posting this.

I want to show a different quick launch (left hand menu) for each page in my SharePoint site, at the moment it shows the same one for every page, sort of like a global menu.

Is there a setting I can change to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved something similar to this by disabling the Quick Launch menu, and instead using a custom links web part positioned on the left hand side on each page. This allowed me to provide the pages with a unique let of links.

This may or may not look correct depending on what masterpage you are using. I was using a custom masterpage that had branding at the top but the content section of the page was open for configuration by dropping webparts onto it.

A more memory heavy solution would be to have each page on a separate sub-site. The parent site could have links to each sub-site, and when you click into them you would see a different set of links on the left hand side. If the branding is the same throughout all the sites it would not be noticeable to the users that they are on a separate site.